# "Can you answer these queries I" challenge

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I have tried to solve the following problem on [SPOJ.com](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GSS1/):

> You are given a sequence
>
> ```
> A[1], A[2], ..., A[N] . ( |A[i]| ≤ 15007 , 1 ≤ N ≤ 50000 )
> ```
>
> A query is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> Query(x,y) = Max { a[i]+a[i+1]+...+a[j] ; x ≤ i ≤ j ≤ y }
> ```
>
> Given M queries, your program must output the results of these queries.

When I run it, I get a time limit error, but I don't know why.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 class TestClass {

static int[] dist ; 
static int[][][] vis;
static ArrayList<Integer>[] resu;
static char[][] graph;
static int max;
static int min;
static int[] dp;
static int zz;
static int zzz;
static nodes[] som;
static nodes temp; 
static boolean fin;

static class nodes{

      int sum ;
      int presum;
      int suffsum;
      int max;

      public nodes(){

      }
      public nodes(int sum , int presum , int suffsum , int max){

            this.sum = sum;
            this.presum = presum;
            this.suffsum = suffsum;
            this.max = max;
      }
}

public static nodes merge(nodes a , nodes b){

    nodes result = new nodes();

    result.sum =  a.sum + b.sum;
    result.presum = Math.max(a.presum, a.sum + b.presum);
    result.suffsum = Math.max(b.suffsum, b.sum+a.suffsum);
    result.max  = Math.max(Math.max(a.sum, b.sum), a.suffsum+b.presum);

    return result;

}

public static void maketree(int current ,int a , int b ,int[] arr){
//  System.out.println(a+" "+b+" "+current);
     if(a>b) return;

     if(a==b)
     {
         int x = arr[a];
         nodes newnode = new nodes(x,x,x,x);
         som[current] = newnode;
         return;
     }


     maketree(2*current, a, (a+b)/2, arr);
     maketree(2*current+1, (a+b)/2+1, b, arr);


     som[current] = merge(som[2*current], som[2*current+1]);






}

public static nodes query(int current , int a, int b, int i , int j){

     if(a==i && b==j) return som[current];

     int mid = (a+b)/2;

     if(j<=mid) return query(2*current, a, (a+b)/2, i, j);
     else if(i>mid) return query(2*current+1, (a+b)/2+1, b, i, j);
     else{

         return merge(query(2*current, a, (a+b)/2, i, j), query(2*current+1, (a+b)/2+1, b, i, j));
     }
}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException  {



Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int n = in.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[n+1];
som = new nodes[10000000];
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) a[i]=in.nextInt();

temp = new nodes(Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE);

maketree(1, 1, n, a);

int Q = in.nextInt();

for(int i=0;i<Q;i++){

    int l =in.nextInt();
    int r =in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(query(1, 1, n, l, r).max);
    //System.out.println(som[2].max+ " "+ som[4].max +" "+ som[5].max);
}



}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static int[] dist ; 
static int[][][] vis;
static ArrayList<Integer>[] resu;
static char[][] graph;
static int max;
static int min;
static int[] dp;
static int zz;
static int zzz;
static nodes[] som;
static nodes temp; 
static boolean fin;
```

Your variable names are very hard to understand. What's `dist`? Distance? Then why is it an array? What's `vis`? Visuals? Why is it a 3D array?

Make your variable names clearer, and add comments what it does.

Also, there is inconsistent spacing. You do stuff like:

```
static int[] dist ;
```

and you also do:

```
static int[][][] vis;
```

Be consistent. The conventions are "no space before `;`", so this:

```
static int[][][] vis;
```

is correct. Also:

```
static class nodes{
```

Standard conventions for class names are PascalCase, not camelCase or alllowercase.

Also, I think all your variables need some breathing space:

```
if(j<=mid) return query(2*current, a, (a+b)/2, i, j);
```

should be:

```
if(j <= mid) return query(2 * current, a, (a + b) / 2, i, j);
```

Also, your formatting seems messed up. You have extra spaces everywhere, so try removing them.